# Is there a more concise way of writing this simple PHP conditional?

Tags: php

It seems like there would be a shorter way of writing this:

```
if ($action == 'add' || $action == 'update' || $action == 'delete') {
       // whatever
}
```

is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (in_array($action, array('add', 'update', 'delete'))) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Small typo: you're missing an apostrophe after delete.

Comment: Cleaner, so +1, though less efficient I believe.  Though doubtfully ever an issue with three elements.

Comment: Definitely less efficient, for at least three reasons (lack of shortcut evaluation, requires creating an array and requires searching in an array), but definitely cleaner :)  And unless it's in the middle of some critical loop, the performance penalty will be extremely small.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this form, since it is easier to maintain:

```
if(in_array($action, array('add', 'update', 'delete'))) {

}
```